# Time delta for each element between two elements in a list

Tags: python, list, datetime, for-loop, timedelta

I am trying to get the delta time between each two datetime elements in a list. But every time I try something i get an index error or the values are incorect.
Out of the list I am facing negative values in some cases. This can not be possible given there is no negative time.

Eg: time_delta_list = [-2, 0, 8, 6]

How am I supposed to do this in a for loop?

code:

```
assignment_date = [['US01', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 20, 6, 59)], ['US03', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 9, 8)], ['US02', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 29, 8, 54)], ['US05', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 29, 15, 5)], ['US09', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 57)], ['US10', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 57)], ['US11', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 58)], ['US04', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 59)]]
time_delta_list = []
 

for index, elem in enumerate(assignment_date):     
        
            if index == 0:
                time_delta = elem[1] - datetime(day=7, month=9, year=2020, hour=10, minute=30)
                time_delta_list.append(time_delta)
                
            if index + 1 < len(assignment_date):
                current_date = elem[1]
                next_date = assignment_date[index+1][1]
                
                time_delta = next_date - current_date
                time_delta_list.append(time_delta)


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
              
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delta_time_assignments.py", line 147, in <module>
    next_date = fed_lists[index+1][1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fairly easy with pandas with no need to mess with indexes

```py
import datetime
import pandas

assignment_date = [['US01', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 20, 6, 59)], ['US03', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 28, 9, 8)], ['US02', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 29, 8, 54)], ['US05', datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 29, 15, 5)], ['US09', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 57)], ['US10', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 57)], ['US11', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 58)], ['US04', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 7, 59)]]

df = pandas.DataFrame(assignment_date)
df = df.rename(columns={0:'key', 1:'initial_date'})
initial_date = datetime.datetime(day=7, month=9, year=2020, hour=10, minute=30)

df['shift'] = df['initial_date'].shift(1, fill_value=initial_date)
df['delta'] = df['initial_date'] - df['shift']

print(df)
```

Comment: This is the error I get(I installed pandas ofcourse): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Eindopdracht_2_python.py", line 166, in <module>
    df['shift'] = df2['initial_date'].shift(1, fill_value=initial_date)
NameError: name 'df2' is not defined